# vector<string> push_back crash

Tags: c++, vector

My first motivation is to using "vector< set >" like this:

```
ifstream fin(file)
string line;
vector< set<string> > diag;
set<string> temp_set;
vector<string> temp_vec;
while(getline(fin, line)
{ 
    temp_vec = split(line, " ");
    for(int i = 0;i < temp_vec.size();i ++)
       temp_set.insert(temp_vec[i]);
    diag.push_back(temp_set)
}
```

but it crashed, then I use "vector" to debug the code.
But interesting is that, the program also crashed when I tried to push_back each line of string into the vector. Here is the code that very simple.

```
ifstream fin(file);
string line;
vector<string> diag;
while(getline(fin, line))
    diag.push_back(line);
```

The program will suddenly crashed when reading some line. 
In addition, the file is big about 4G.
Could anyone help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the message you get when it crashes? Run it with the debugger attached (from Visual Studio) and see which code is causing the crash.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling a 64-bit application?  32-bit apps won't be able to load 4G files into a `vector`.  You can check with `std::cout << sizeof(void*) << '\n';` - if it says 4 you're 32-bit, 8 you're 64-bit.

Comment: One usually doesn't need to load a file that big into ram at once. Split it up.

Comment: Try catching exceptions

Comment: yeah, the file is more than 4 gb.@Axalo When I run the program, it doesn't show useful information, just said doesn't work and cancel. @Tony D

Comment: I think the problem will truly be the x64 platform.

Answer (score 1):

With this code here your `temp_set` just keeps getting bigger and bigger because it does not get emptied between lines:

```
ifstream fin(file);
string line;
vector< set<string> > diag;
set<string> temp_set;
vector<string> temp_vec;
while(getline(fin, line)
{ 
    temp_vec = split(line, " ");
    for(int i = 0;i < temp_vec.size();i ++)
       temp_set.insert(temp_vec[i]); // when is this set emptied?
    diag.push_back(temp_set);
}
```

Maybe try this:

```
ifstream fin(file);
string line;
vector< set<string> > diag;
vector<string> temp_vec;
while(getline(fin, line)
{
    temp_vec = split(line, " ");
    // no need for loop
    // construct a new set each time
    set<string> temp_set(temp_vec.begin(), temp_vec.end());
    diag.push_back(temp_set);
}
```

If you have **C++11** you can be even more efficient like this:

```
std::ifstream fin(file);
std::string line;
std::vector<std::set<std::string> > diag;
std::vector<std::string> temp_vec;

while(std::getline(fin, line))
{
    temp_vec = split(line, " ");
    diag.emplace_back(temp_vec.begin(), temp_vec.end());
}
```

Comment: I should sorry that I just forget to edit the code carefully, actually I have tried this "erase" function already in my code. But it still crashes. Make me feel confused. Any other comments?? Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, the problem because the x64 platform.